# Change homepage template, depending on admin setting

Tags: 7, theming

**Problem:** I have a content type called "Homepage" of which there is only one node instance (which is pointed to as the front page), that contains a bunch of editable fields so the client can update certain front page content in several places.

They want to be able to, now and then, change the front page to a slightly different layout to focus on a call to action. This will probably be an

- extra content-editable text area
- a driver image

That will take the place of an image on the front page. This image is output in `node--homepage.tpl.php` as you might expect.

**My proposed solution**:

- Create two new fields in the Homepage content: driver text, driver image.
- Create an admin page, or add to an existing admin form a button: "Driver mode". When this button is enabled,
- Make the Homepage content type reference a new template that hides the old image and outputs the new fields.

Is it possible to do this - use a new template depending on some set variable, or should I have some logic in my `node--homepage.tpl.php` that conditionally outputs one bunch of HTML or another depending on the variable set in the admin? E.g. (rough code, ignore syntax/logic errors)

```
<?php

if (variable_get('driver_mode'))
{
   print render($content['field_driver_image']);
   print render($content['field_driver_text']);
}
else
{
   print render($content['field_homepage_image']);
}

?>
```

So basically, I'm asking what you think is a simple, clean and/or Drupal way to solve my problem above? Note that the code above is just a general example to support what I'm trying to achieve, no need to analyse it's correctness, I'm more interested in what your approach would be - should I perhaps be preprocessing the output in template.php depending on whether driver mode is on or off, so that I only output one variable, which produces the desired output depending on state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version is:

1. Create needed fields (driver image and driver text) for node type
2. Add checkbox field to the frontpage node type ('Driver mode')
3. Use template_preprocess_node(&$variables) or hook_node_view() to make some changes if checkbox field is checked

Comment: Yes, adding the checkbox to the content type seems much better, and preprocess does make sense to seperate the display and logic. Thankyou!